# If the self-wedge product $\wedge^k F$ of a coherent sheaf $F$ is locally free, then is $F$ locally free?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a connected normal complex analytic space and $F$  a coherent sheaf on $X$. We define the rank of $F$ at  $x\in X$ to be the $\mathbb
C$-dimension of the $\mathbb
C$-vector space $F_x/m_x F_x$, where $m_x$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ and $F_x$ the stalk of $F$  at $x$.

Assume that the maximal rank of $F$ at any point of $X$ is $n$.  Assume further that  there exists a positive integer $k\leq n$ such that $\wedge^k F$  is locally free.

**Question: Is $F$ locally free?**

Any remarks or ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks a lot.  Good idea. I have reedit my question to avoid the case you proposed.

Comment: Just in case, what definition of $\wedge^k F$ you are using?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Interesting! I wonder if that example is the "simplest" counterexample to the post's question? I was trying to make something work with the affine scheme $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}])$ Take the ideal $I = (2,1+\sqrt(5))$ in $R = \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}]$. $R$ is a Dedekind domain so any non-principal ideal is projective and not free. But one can show that $\bigwedge^2 I \neq 0$. Since exterior powers preserve projectives, $\bigwedge^2 I$ is projective and finitely generated, so is finite locally free.

Comment: @T.Ochse: I thought that $\bigwedge^2$ commuted to localization, hence $\bigwedge^2 I$ would vanish (since $I$ is locally free of rank $1$)… could you elaborate?

Comment: @Sasha  It may be defined stalkwisely  to be $(\wedge ^k F)_x:=\wedge ^k F_x$ (I cannot make clear whether the presheaf associated with $U\mapsto \wedge ^k F(U)$ is a sheaf).

Comment: @Aphelli: You are correct. My choice of $R$ is actually a PID since it is Dedekind and one of the real quadratic UFDs. If you look at $I$ inside of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ instead, then I believe it is still true that $\bigwedge^2 I \neq 0$ since you can construct a non-zero alternating bilinear map $I\times I \to R$. But this probably causes extra problems since I don't think $I$ is invertible (hence not projective).